# Pseudo-randomly pick an element from a list only if it was not chosen yet

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

Is there a way to "pseudo"-randomly select an element from a list that wasn't chosen before? I know about the `choice` function, which returns a random item from the list, but without taking into account previous chosen items. I could keep track of which elements were already picked, and keep randomly choose another not yet selected item, but this might include nested loops, etc.

I could also for example remove the element chose from the list at each iteration, but this does not seem a good solution, too.

My question is: is there a "aware" `choice` function that selects only items that weren't chosen before? Note that I'm not asking how to implement such a function, but possible solutions are of course well-accepted too.

Comment: Shuffle the list and pop elements from the top.

Comment: You could use `random.sample` or `random.shuffle`. More context is needed to appropriately answer your question.

Comment: Yes, I think I am going with `random.shuffle`, since it doesn't matter in my case if the original list is changed or not, if other solutions don't come out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you can shuffle the list and then use the `list.pop()` method.  Here is an example:

```
>>> import random
>>> mylist = list(range(5))
>>> print(mylist)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> random.shuffle(mylist)
>>> print(mylist)
[4, 2, 0, 1, 3]
>>> while len(mylist) > 0:
...     print(mylist.pop())
...
3
1
0
2
4
>>> print(mylist)
[]
```

Comment: Your code leads to an exception being raised: `TypeError: 'range' object does not support item assignment`. You need to cast the range object to a list, e.g. `mylist = list(range(5))`.

Comment: @Arn: You're right. In the time I wrote that I dealt much more with Python 2 than 3, so it looks like I just tested it in a Python 2 console and then added the parentheses for print. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Shuffle the list and pop elements from the top. That will only produce each list element once.